# Default value for grails.json.legacy.builder in Grails 2.5.0

Tags: grails

What is the default value for grails.json.legacy.builder in Grails 2.5.0?

The [Grails 2.5.0 docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/guide/theWebLayer.html#moreOnJSONBuilder) say that it should be set to `false` in Config.groovy to use the "new" `JsonBuilder`.

However, the  "new" `JsonBuilder` was introduced in Grails 1.2, which was a long time ago, so I can't imagine that the current default would be `true`.

I searched the Grails code for usages of this property, by couldn't find any.  This property might not even be used anymore, despite still being in the docs.